# Open multiple instances of Drive PDF Viewer on Redmagic

Tags: google-drive, pdf

Opening a new pdf file from redmagic's file explorer (or the google file explorer) replaces the old instance of the drive pdf viewer and the previous pdf file with the new pdf file, unlike Samsung phones where it allows both to be open at once.

A workaround I have found is to upload the pdf file to drive and open it from there, then I can open any number of pdf files simultaneously. Is there a fix for this or a better workaround?

I am using RedMagic 7 Pro.